# Clean magento tables before data migration

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento-2.1, database, migration

I'm in the process of migrating magento 1.6 to magento 2.1. I only need clients (and their addresses) as well as products.  What tables can I truncate beforehand?

Found a script that gets rid of:

```
TRUNCATE `sales_order`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order_datetime`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order_decimal`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order_entity`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order_int`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order_text`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order_varchar`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address_item`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item`;   
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item_option`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_item`;
TRUNCATE `sendfriend_log`;
TRUNCATE `tag`;
TRUNCATE `tag_relation`;
TRUNCATE `tag_summary`;
TRUNCATE `wishlist`;
TRUNCATE `log_quote`;
TRUNCATE `report_event`;
```

But I'm wondering if some other tables are safe to get rid of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can clean also below table:

```
dataflow_batch_export
dataflow_batch_import
log_customer
log_summary
log_summary_type
log_url
log_url_info
log_visitor
log_visitor_info
log_visitor_online
```

**which are also not need for migration, just truncate these table at the magento1 system before start migration.**

Comment: See answer 2. Is it logic to add this into the answer? (now I am not so sure)

Answer (score 3):

You need to run following query from your magento-1 database, before migration. So it will remove unneccessary data.

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_export;
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_import;
TRUNCATE log_customer;
TRUNCATE log_quote;
TRUNCATE log_summary;
TRUNCATE log_summary_type;
TRUNCATE log_url;
TRUNCATE log_url_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_online;
TRUNCATE report_viewed_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_compared_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_event;
TRUNCATE index_event;
TRUNCATE catalog_compare_item;
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answers (and adds to) your question:

https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/vm2mage/699-cleaning-up-magento-entries